# Highlight div on hover and fade out other divs using just css3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade the other divs when one div is highlighted on hover.
I know this is possible using jquery but I'm wondering if it's possible with just using css3.

I did try using jquery with the code below but because the divs
do not have the class .highLight from the start and only when hovered, all of the divs end up faded out from the start due to using .panel:not(.highLight){opacity:0.5;}

Hope this makes sense.

Jquery

```
$('.panel').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('highLight');
});
```

CSS

```
.highLight{
    background-color: #333333;
}
.panel{
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    transition:0.3s;
    opacity:1;
}
.panel:not(.highLight){
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

HTML Below

```
<section id="areas">
<div class="container content">

    <div class="projects">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: no jsBin, no jsFiddle :(

Comment: Can you not just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jf5AP/

Comment: here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r1chyr1ch/5wyt5/7/) to get the idea across  at the moment all of it gets highlighted where I'm trying to get just the .panel to highlight on hover and the others fade.  @SombreErmine Your example just shows hover state with the other divs not fading away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only selector you want to adjust of your current project is:

```
#areas:hover > div {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
#areas:hover > div:hover,
#areas:hover > div:hover * {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #ffa;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

to:

```
.panel
{
    opacity: .5;
   
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#areas:hover > div:hover .panel 
{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #ffa;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

The first part of the CSS is when none of the panels are selected (a default layout). I just set the opacity to 0.5 to keep it visible, but you could also completely fade it out.

Now, the second part happens when you hover the div element in the #area div OR when you hover the #area div itself. The CSS settings will only be set for the .panel. In this case, the opacity will be set to 1 and a light background color will be set.

So the hover is only the trigger and the element after it will be the element that will actually be used, in this case.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5wyt5/10/)**

**EDIT**

If you want to add a function to let the non-hovered elements disappear as soon as you hover, you should add this code :

```
#areas:hover > div:not(:hover) > .panel
{
    opacity: 0; 
    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

I do use the [:not()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector to exclude the :hover pseudo class.

So in this case the #area is the trigger, the div is the excluder and the .panel is the actual element that will be affected.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wyt5/14/)**

Comment: Works well but I'm also trying to fade out the other boxes at the same time when one box is highlighted.

Comment: Hi, I used the code and it worked. Here is the link to the working one. http://jsfiddle.net/r1chyr1ch/5wyt5/15/ I did delete a div because orignally I had it before <section>, but now I'v moved the class into <section>. **Thankyou**

Answer (score 3):

How about this CSS

```
#areas .panel {
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
            transition:0.3s;
}    

#areas:hover .panel {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#areas:hover .panel:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/ytsTR/

Comment: When your inbetween divs with the cursor, all divs are faded out still due to the opacity hover state on #areas.@phil I have e demo here to show what I'm working on.  http://jsfiddle.net/r1chyr1ch/5wyt5/7/

Comment: I'm trying to just get the curved box (.panel) highlighted on hover and the others fade out. @Phil

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest I'd suggest:

```
/* aesthetics, this block doesn't really matter; it's just to help visualise */
section, div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
}

section div {
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* vendor-prefixes stripped for brevity */
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

section > div:hover,
section > div:hover * {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #ffa;
    /* vendor-prefixes stripped for brevity */
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M8H6R/1/).

On the assumption you want them fully visible until the `section` is hovered:

```
section > div {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* vendor-prefixes stripped for brevity */
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

section:hover > div {
    opacity: 0.5;
    /* vendor-prefixes stripped for brevity */
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

section:hover > div:hover,
section:hover > div:hover * {
    opacity: 1;
    /* vendor-prefixes stripped for brevity */
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M8H6R/2/).

Comment: I think he wants the initial state to be full opacity until one of them is hovered

Comment: @Phil: yep, agreed; was writing that down as you commented. :)

Comment: Thanky you for the reply. This does work but if you hover over the section div it's all faded out when I would need it still full opacity.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r1chyr1ch/5wyt5/7/) to show what I'm working on. Wondering if i'ts possible to change just the .panel on hover? at the moment it changes the .btn color where I just want the panel color to change and the other panels to fade on hover.

Answer (score 0):

/// css

```
  .content .testing {
          -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
          -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
          -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
          transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  }

   .content:hover .testing {
           opacity: 0.5;
   }

   .content .testing:hover {
          opacity: 1 !important;
   }
```

///html

```
    <section id="areas">
        <div class="container content">

            <div class="projects testing">
              <div class="panel">
               Div one
            </div>
       </div>

       <div class="blog testing">
            <div class="panel">
                 Div two
       </div>

       </div>
            <div class="contact testing">
                 <div class="panel">
                     Div three
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
      </div>
   </section>
```

Hope this helps