# How to fade child div when parent is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that has class name `ordershape` and it contains another div `fad-res`.

I want that when I would hover over a particular `ordershape`, I want to show the corressponding`fad-res` whose parent div I hovered, while other divs must be hidden.

```
<div class="ordershape">
    <div class="fad-res">1</div>
</div>
<div class="ordershape">
    <div class="fad-res">2</div>
</div>
<div class="ordershape">
    <div class="fad-res">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: refer this link:->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170481/highlight-div-on-hover-and-fade-out-other-divs-using-just-css3
this may helpful for you to solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight div on hover and fade out other divs using just css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170481/highlight-div-on-hover-and-fade-out-other-divs-using-just-css3)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid since you haven't closed the div with the class `ordershape`

No reason to use jquery for this, CSS can easily achieve this:

```
.ordershape:hover .fad-res{
  display:block;
}
```

**Demo CSS**

```css
.fad-res{
  display:none;
}

.ordershape{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.ordershape:hover .fad-res{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="ordershape"> <div class="fad-res">1</div>
</div>
<div class="ordershape"> <div class="fad-res">2</div>
</div>
<div class="ordershape"> <div class="fad-res">3</div>
</div>
```

If you want to do it with jquery do it like this.

```
$(".ordershape").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find(".fad-res").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find(".fad-res").hide();
});
```

**Demo jQuery**

```js
$(".ordershape").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find(".fad-res").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).find(".fad-res").hide();
});
```

```css
.fad-res{
  display:none;
}

.ordershape{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ordershape"> <div class="fad-res">1</div>
</div>
<div class="ordershape"> <div class="fad-res">2</div>
</div>
<div class="ordershape"> <div class="fad-res">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use javascript for that - rely on the CSS `transition` and `opacity` properties instead, with `:hover` selector.

```css
.fad-res {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #555555;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
}

.ordershape {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.ordershape:hover .fad-res {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ordershape">
  <div class="fad-res">1</div>
</div>

<div class="ordershape">
  <div class="fad-res">2</div>
</div>

<div class="ordershape">
  <div class="fad-res">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try the `jquery` version this way

```js
$(".ordershape").hover(function(){

   $(this).find(".fad-res").toggle();
})
```

```css
.fad-res{
 display : none;
 
}
.ordershape{

width : 20px;
height: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ordershape">
    <div class="fad-res">1</div>
  </div>
<div class="ordershape">
     <div class="fad-res">2</div>
     </div>
 <div class="ordershape">
      <div class="fad-res">3</div>
      </div>
```